# Enabling and setting cache period : Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-boot

I set the following properties in my spring boot App:

```
spring.resources.chain.cache=true
spring.resources.cache-period=604800
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/**/resources/**
```

In my Chrome browser network, for some resources i see that the property Cache-Control is added :

```
 Cache-Control:max-age=604800
```

But they are not loaded from memory cache, i still see the full size in network. Also the status still 200, and not 304. Does this mean that, they are not cached ?